# How to find which global variables are used in a function by using LLVM API?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to collect all the global variables used in a function for LLVm IR code. Is there any LLVM API can do this? For example,`as the following code.

```
int a,b;
int fun(){return a+b;}
```

global variables a and b are used in fun(), I need to collect a and b in a set.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any single API method that does that, but writing one should be straightforward:

```cpp
void getGlobalsUsedByFunction(const Function &F, set<GlobalValue*> *Globals) {
  for (const BasicBlock &BB : F)
    for (const Instruction &I : BB)
      for (const Value *Op : I.operands())
        if (const GlobalValue* G = dyn_cast<GlobalValue>(*Op))
          Globals->insert(G);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Oak's solution should work. I'll just add that for a more efficient approach (in a typical translation unit), what I'd do is walk the `users()` list of each global var (see [this section](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-def-use-use-def-chains) in the LLVM programmer manual) and note the functions it appears in, and then would infer from that.

But this is, admittedly, a tradeoff. If you have an (non-typical) translation unit with little code and a lot of globals, Oak's solution will be better.